# How to create a new doc within a javascript function in OrientDB

Tags: javascript, orientdb

I would like to create a new Document within a javascript function which is triggered when an doc is updated, and is triggered before update.

The new Document is based in the document that I am trying to update.

My function is something like that:

```
var formattedDate = getDateUTC();
print(formattedDate);
var db = orient.getDatabase();
var newDocument = new com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument("Item_Process");
newDocument = doc;
newDocument.field("final_date").value = formattedDate;
newDocument.save();
db.commit();
```

The object to update is updated, but a new document is not created.
There is not any error.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitude this line:

```
newDocument.field("final_date").value = formattedDate;
```

with this one:

```
newDocument.field("final_date", formattedDate);
```

Hope it helps

Regards